# how to calculate month and year ago in kotlin android studio "time ago"

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, retrofit

this is my code to parse "Time Ago" from database Created_at , i just got Days ago, the months & years ago is not showing..

```
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
private fun formatTimeAgo(date1: String): String {
    var conversionTime =""

    try{
        val format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"

        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(format)
        sdf.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")

        val datetime= Calendar.getInstance()
        val date2= sdf.format(datetime.time).toString()

        val Past = sdf.parse(date1)
        val Now = sdf.parse(date2)
        val diff = Now.time - Past.time

        val diffsec = diff  / 1000
        val diffmin = diff / (60 * 1000)
        val diffhours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000)
        val diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        val diffMonts = diff / (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) -> show warning **This operation has led to an overflow**
        val diffYears = diff / (24 * 365 * 60 * 60 * 1000) -> show warning **This operation has led to an overflow**

        when {
            diff<diffYears -> {
                conversionTime+= " $diffYears years ago"
            }
            diffMonts>1 -> {
                conversionTime+= (diffMonts-diffYears/12).toString()+" months ago "
            }
            diffDays>1 -> {
                conversionTime += (diffDays-diffMonts/30).toString()+" days ago "
            }
            diffhours>1 -> {
                conversionTime+=(diffhours-diffDays*24).toString()+" hours ago "
            }
            diffmin>1 -> {
                conversionTime+=(diffmin-diffhours*60).toString()+" min ago "
            }
            diffsec>1 -> {
                conversionTime+= " Just Now "
            }
        }

    }catch (ex:java.lang.Exception){
        Log.e("formatTimeAgo",ex.toString())
    }
    return conversionTime
}
```

this is what i got in my app :

[please see this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kux8.jpg)

i dont know whats wrong in my code, please somebody help me :(

thanks in advance..

Comment: if this is not a question about android-studio, nor about retrofit, why include those tags?

Comment: this code use android studio ide + retrofit to parse the data from the database

Comment: the code could just as well be written in notepad, it has no bearing on the issue you are having with dates. Same for the parsing, it doesn't really matter, you already have it as a String (the function parameter), a String coming from retrofit, is the same as a String comming from anywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works for me

```
var result = format.format(it)

val diff = Calendar.getInstance().time.time - it.time

val oneSec = 1000L
val oneMin: Long = 60 * oneSec
val oneHour: Long = 60 * oneMin
val oneDay: Long = 24 * oneHour
val oneMonth: Long = 30 * oneDay
val oneYear: Long = 365 * oneDay

val diffMin: Long = diff / oneMin
val diffHours: Long = diff / oneHour
val diffDays: Long = diff / oneDay
val diffMonths: Long = diff / oneMonth
val diffYears: Long = diff / oneYear

when {
    diffYears > 0 -> {
        result += " $diffYears years ago"
    }
    diffMonths > 0 && diffYears < 1 -> {
        result += " ${(diffMonths - diffYears / 12)} months ago "
    }
    diffDays > 0 && diffMonths < 1 -> {
        result += " ${(diffDays - diffMonths / 30)} days ago "
    }
    diffHours > 0 && diffDays < 1 -> {
        result += " ${(diffHours - diffDays * 24)} hours ago "
    }
    diffMin > 0 && diffHours < 1 -> {
        result += " ${(diffMin - diffHours * 60)} min ago "
    }
    diffMin < 1 -> {
        result += " just now"
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]